# ajax call with html form won't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck.

It's like the script doesn't have any function at all.

```
        <script>
            $("#continue").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "dbc.php?check=First",
           data: {full_name : $('#full_name').val()
                 usr_email : $('#usr_email').val()},
           success: function(msg){
               if(msg==1){
                  $("#First_1").hide();
                  $("#Next_2").toggle(); 
               }else{
                  alert(msg)
               }               
            }
         });
         return false;
    }); 
        </script>

        <form action="index.php?page=checkin" method="post" name="regForm">
     <div id="First_1">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
                                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 5px;">
                        Fullständiga namn: 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input name="full_name" type="text" id="full_name" class="required"> 
                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 5px;">
                        Email:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input name="usr_email" type="text" id="usr_email" class="required email">
                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 5px;">
                        Sex: 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <select name="sex">
                        <option value="male">Kille</option>
                        <option value="female">Tjej</option>
                        </select>
                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="submit" id="continue" value="Continue">
                        </td>
                </table>
        </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

With this when i press continue it should send ajax call, but it doesn't. When i press Continue it just takes me to the form´s action="index.php?page=checkin", even if theres return false; on click(in the script)? I even tried to change the form line and inserted onsubmit="return false;" but then nothing happens at all when i click on the button.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is it's doing the default action, because none of your jQuery code is running :)  When your code runs, the `id="continue"` element isn't there yet, so `$("#continue")` doesn't find anything to bind a `click` handler to.  It's an easy fix, wrap your code in a `document.ready` call, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#continue").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "dbc.php?check=First",
       data: {full_name : $('#full_name').val()
             usr_email : $('#usr_email').val()},
       success: function(msg){
           if(msg==1){
              $("#First_1").hide();
              $("#Next_2").toggle(); 
           }else{
              alert(msg)
           }               
        }
     });
     return false;
  });
});
```

By doing this it'll wait until the DOM is ready, and your elements are there to find/bind to.  Also instead of attaching to the `#continue` button's `click` event, it's usually better to attach to the form's `submit` handler, so it's caught there, so instead of this:

```
$("#continue").click(function () {
```

You would do this:

```
$("form[name='regForm']").submit(function() {
```

With everything else staying the same.

Comment: I have my code like that now, and i am still having no results, it still takes me to form action, is there any special place i should have the code? And the suggest with attaching it wit the form´s submit handler, its a no, because as you see in the code, the forms submit is in div #Next_2, that get's toggled. The call is for checking if full_name and usr_email is valid.

Comment: @Karem - You can check all of this on `submit` as well...this is how the jQuery validation plugin works for example :)  Are you getting any JavaScript errors?  It's still behaving as if your code isn't running correctly, erroring out and not attaching, check your console for errors and see if there's anything there.

Comment: I get this: missing } after property list, success: function(msg) {

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a typo and it looks like in your data field.

I would suggest doing

```
data: "value1="+$("#val1").val()+"&value2="+$("#val2").val()
```

Also a good way to debug javascript is to open up chrome's console or in firefox use firebugs console and when you perform the action it will usually inform you of a problem or lack thereof.

One last note: I would suggest using json in your return from php, this way you can provide user with a more catered message.  For example, lets say your form doesnt validate server side (you are validating server side right?) you can return to client a nice message explaining to them waht did not validate.  How to do this?

```
  $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "dbc.php",
           data: "val1="+$(#val1).val()+"&val2="+$(#val2).val(), 
           success: function(json){
               if(json.error){
                  //notify user of error message
                  $(#statusDiv).(json.message); 
               }else{
                  //perform success 

               }               
            }
         });
```

And on the server side to use something such as

```
echo json_encode(array("error"=>1, "message"=>"<insert validation problems here>"));
```

This will on success function have access via json.error, or json.message.

Comment: ok i changed to this now:  data: "full_name="+$("#full_name").val()+"&usr_email="+$("#usr_email").val() when i see in fierfox console it says missing } after property list, success: function(msg){ .. what does this mean and i cant see where theres missing a }

Answer (score 0):

In your new code on phpbin you need a comma after the line:

```
 data: "full_name="+$("#full_name").val()+"&usr_email="+$("#usr_email").val(), // <-- COMMA HERE
```

Or, in your old code (which is nicer since you don't have to deal with concatenating the data url yourself), you were missing a comma also, between the two lines:

```
data: {full_name : $('#full_name').val(), // <-- COMMA HERE
         usr_email : $('#usr_email').val()},
```

ALSO, you need a semicolon after this line:

```
alert(msg); // <-- SEMICOLON HERE
```

;)

Comment: It starts to work now, i believe, although when i press continue now, i get an alert with nothing in it? I mean no error message in it.. Why? Here's dbc.php?check=First http://phpbin.net/x/249121011

Comment: There could be an error on the PHP side? Why don't you echo something else if there's an error - add an else statement after the last if:
if (empty($err)) {echo 1;} else {echo "there was an error";}